# Skew an HTML element in the Z direction

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transforms

Below is the base "un-skewed" element we want to skew in both the *Z* and *X* direction to create a **diagonal skew**.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  perspective: 30rem;
}
body, div, span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
section > div > div {
  transform: scaleX( 0.5 ) scaleZ( 0.5 );
}
div div:nth-of-type( 2 ) {
  transform: rotateY( 180deg ) rotateZ( 90deg );
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0rem 0rem 0rem 0.5rem #444 inset;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: rgba( 200,200,200,0.25 );
}
span:nth-of-type( 1 ) { transform: translateZ( 5rem ); }
span:nth-of-type( 2 ) { transform: rotateY( 90deg ) translateZ( 5rem ); }
span:nth-of-type( 3 ) { transform: rotateY( -90deg ) translateZ( 5rem ); }
```

```html
<style>
  .rotate_y, .rotate_x {
    animation-name: rotateY;
    animation-duration: 6s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }
  @keyframes rotateY {
    0% { transform: rotateY( 0deg ); }
    100% { transform: rotateY( 360deg ); }  
  }
  .rotate_x {
    animation-name: rotateX;
  }
  @keyframes rotateX {
    0% { transform: rotateX( 0deg ); }
    100% { transform: rotateX( 360deg ); }  
  }
</style>

<section class='rotate_y'>
  <div class='rotate_x'>
    <div>
      <div> <span></span><span></span><span></span> </div>
      <div> <span></span><span></span><span></span> </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Adding `transform: skewX( 45deg )` to `body section > div > div` in the HTML window works as expected:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  perspective: 30rem;
}
body, div, span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
section > div > div {
  transform: scaleX( 0.5 ) scaleZ( 0.5 );
}
div div:nth-of-type( 2 ) {
  transform: rotateY( 180deg ) rotateZ( 90deg );
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0rem 0rem 0rem 0.5rem #444 inset;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: rgba( 200,200,200,0.25 );
}
span:nth-of-type( 1 ) { transform: translateZ( 5rem ); }
span:nth-of-type( 2 ) { transform: rotateY( 90deg ) translateZ( 5rem ); }
span:nth-of-type( 3 ) { transform: rotateY( -90deg ) translateZ( 5rem ); }
```

```html
<style>
  .rotate_y, .rotate_x {
    animation-name: rotateY;
    animation-duration: 6s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }
  @keyframes rotateY {
    0% { transform: rotateY( 0deg ); }
    100% { transform: rotateY( 360deg ); }  
  }
  .rotate_x {
    animation-name: rotateX;
  }
  @keyframes rotateX {
    0% { transform: rotateX( 0deg ); }
    100% { transform: rotateX( 360deg ); }  
  }
  
  /* skew in the X direction added */
  body section > div > div {
    transform: scaleX( 0.5 ) scaleZ( 0.5 ) skewX( 45deg );
  }
</style>

<section class='rotate_y'>
  <div class='rotate_x'>
    <div>
      <div> <span></span><span></span><span></span> </div>
      <div> <span></span><span></span><span></span> </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

`transform: skewX( 45deg )` and `transform: skewY( 45deg )` work perfectly. However adding `transform: skewZ( 45deg )` does not.

*Is skewing in the Z direction a part of the CSS spec? And if not what is a good workaround?*

Below is an example snippet of what happens when I set `skewZ()`. ( it nullifies all transform properties as if it's an invalid CSS rule. )

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  perspective: 30rem;
}
body, div, span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
section > div > div {
  transform: scaleX( 0.5 ) scaleZ( 0.5 );
}
div div:nth-of-type( 2 ) {
  transform: rotateY( 180deg ) rotateZ( 90deg );
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0rem 0rem 0rem 0.5rem #444 inset;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: rgba( 200,200,200,0.25 );
}
span:nth-of-type( 1 ) { transform: translateZ( 5rem ); }
span:nth-of-type( 2 ) { transform: rotateY( 90deg ) translateZ( 5rem ); }
span:nth-of-type( 3 ) { transform: rotateY( -90deg ) translateZ( 5rem ); }
```

```html
<style>
  .rotate_y, .rotate_x {
    animation-name: rotateY;
    animation-duration: 6s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }
  @keyframes rotateY {
    0% { transform: rotateY( 0deg ); }
    100% { transform: rotateY( 360deg ); }  
  }
  .rotate_x {
    animation-name: rotateX;
  }
  @keyframes rotateX {
    0% { transform: rotateX( 0deg ); }
    100% { transform: rotateX( 360deg ); }  
  }
  
  /* skewing in the Z direction doesn't register */
  body section > div > div {
    transform: scaleX( 0.5 ) scaleZ( 0.5 ) skewX( 45deg ) skewZ( 45deg );
  }
</style>

<section class='rotate_y'>
  <div class='rotate_x'>
    <div>
      <div> <span></span><span></span><span></span> </div>
      <div> <span></span><span></span><span></span> </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**The desired result here is for the html element in question to be skewed both in the Z and X direction simultaneously.**

Comment: `skewZ()` is an invalid property. The only valid axes along which skew can be applied are X and Y axes. You'll probably have to use some other method to achieve the `skewZ` effect. May be try using `transform-origin()`?

Comment: @sagar1025 Yeah, it appears so :(. I'm curious if there's a straightforward way to implement diagonal skew.

Comment: Since skew is only applied on a 2D plane, `rotate3d()` is what you need. If you need to shear in 3D space, `rotate3d(0,0,0,45deg)` might just do the trick

Comment: @sagar1025 example or it doesn't work lol. Actually since asking this question I kind of solved it already. Use a wrapper element to skewX. Rotate child 90deg then skewX again. I'm still curious for more elegant solutions if there's some out there though.

Comment: well, skewZ() doesn't make a lot of sense. How you expect to skew a 2D element in the third axis ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif We are skewing a 3D element, not a 2D one. We can slant left/right or up and down. Why not back or forward? ( and I would expect skewing in the Z direction would bring an element into the third dimension anyway )

Comment: there is no 3D element in CSS, you are creating a 3D element by combining 2D elements.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I guess your point is to explain why there is no transform: `skewZ()` in the CSS spec. I understand :(. However we can `transalteZ()` on a 2-dimensional element. We can `rotateZ()` and even `scaleZ()` on a 2-dimensional element is valid CSS ( which also makes little sense ). But I understand `skewZ()` is unfortunately not in the spec :(. It's essentially just a `skewX()` rotated 90 degrees around the Y Axis if we were to try to implement this using a parent and child element. Is there a simple way however to get this effect without using a rotated and skewed parent element? Thx!

Comment: *However we can transalteZ() on a 2-dimensional element* --> we translate a 2D inside a 3D space, so it's logical to have a translateZ and rotateZ because they are relative to the space not the element (such transformation doesn't distort the element, they move it). Same logic for scaleZ(), try to apply it to an element and nothing will happen, it have a meanig only when dealing in a 3D space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is not the possibility to set simply a skewZ, because it is *harder* than that.

The skew that you already know, are 2D transforms. What they really are, is skewX (for the Y axis), and skewY (for the X axis).

When going 3D, you would have

- skewX for Y
- skewX for Z
- skewY for X
- skewY for Z
- skewZ for X
- skewZ for Y

Not so easy !

There are 2 ways to get some skewZ.

First, using a rotation, as you already commented. Just rememeber to unset it:

```
transform: rotateX(90deg) skewX(10deg) rotateX(-90deg)
```

The other one is to use a transform matrix . This is a matrix with the clasicals skews

```
1          skewY      0        0
skewX         1       0        0
0             0       1        0
0             0       0        1
```

And this is a matrix with the Z skews

```
1             0      skewZ/x        0
0             1      skewZ/y        0
0             0       1             0
0             0       0             1
```

Comment: I don’t understand why your matrix3d() values work. But I finally got around to testing this knowing nothing about matrix beforehand... and it does in fact act as a “skewZ” would... thank you. Still confused af but thank you.